# jGrasp reverted my Edited files back

Tags: java, file, jgrasp

So I've worked on three java class files I downloaded and I've been heavily editing them. When I turn my compiler on today, they REVERTED back to their ORIGINAL FORM, as if my edits were cut entirely. I don't know what to do, any suggestions? I don't think a system restore will affect them so I really need help with this.

Comment: Did you save your edits to disk?  If so, have you checked those files in another editor?  If not, why not?!

Comment: You should report this as a bug to the JGrasp developers, even if it turns out to be your error. This should never happen.

Comment: Yes I've checked in eclipse and it's gone as well. The files look like when I first downloaded them without my edits. I even downloaded and ran "Recuva" to recover any of the files but it couldn't find them. I don't understand. I sent my files to someone else to proof read via email so when this bug happened and I went back to see if I could download them back, they were also back in their original forms. And I definitely compiled and saved the files so I don't understand what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not anything jGRASP is doing, there isn't any such capability in it. If you have "Auto Save" off (it's on by default), then modified files will be backed up before a compile and restored afterward, but then they would still be marked as edited and you would get an "unsaved files" warning when closing jGRASP.

Is this just a hard disk, or some kind of network file system where they may have had a crash and done a restore without telling you?

Are you sure you don't have two copies of your project, and that you're looking at the wrong copy?